# Roots of $f(x)=x^3-x^2-2x+1$

Tags: analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

We can prove using a monotony study that the function $f(x)=x^3-x^2-2x+1$ has three real roots. However, when I solve the equation $f(x)=0$ using Mathematica, I get
$$x_1=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{7^{2/3}}{3 \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)\right)^{1/3}}+\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{7}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)\right)^{1/3}$$
$$x_2=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)^{2/3} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{6} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(\frac{7}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)\right)^{1/3}$$
$$x_3=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)^{2/3} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(\frac{7}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)\right)^{1/3}$$

Since those roots are real, then maybe there's a way to write them without using the complex number $i$?

Comment: If the roots are real no probably about it. Of course theres no reason to assume the answer will be easy or pretty. Did you try polar coordinates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the complex numbers even when there are three real roots. That was a real puzzle when the cubic was first solved.

Read about the *casus irreducibilis*: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 4):

This is Example 9.2.2 in the first edition of *Galois Theory* by David A. Cox. He gives the polynomial, on page 239, as $y^3 + y^2 - 2 y -1.$

Easy enough to confirm the next bit with trig identities for $\cos 2t$ and $\cos 3t$ in terms of $\cos t \; .$ We have $\cos 2t = 2 \cos^2 t - 1$ and $\cos 3t = 4 \cos^3 t - 3 \cos t.$ The easiest proof is what Gauss intended, take a nontrivial seventh root of unity $\omega,$ so that $\omega^6 + \omega^5 + \omega^4 + \omega^3 + \omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0.$ Then take $x = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega},$ calculate $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1,$ and confirm that $(x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1) \omega^3 = \omega^6 + \omega^5 + \omega^4 + \omega^3 + \omega^2 + \omega + 1,$ which is then zero.

The roots of $x^3 + x^2 - 2 x -1$ are $$ 2 \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; 2 \cos \left( \frac{4 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; 2 \cos \left( \frac{6 \pi}{7} \right) \; . \; $$ **Yours are negative of these,** therefore
$$ 2 \cos \left( \frac{ \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; 2 \cos \left( \frac{3 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; 2 \cos \left( \frac{5 \pi}{7} \right) \; . \; $$

from Cox:

[image]

From Reuschle (1875)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the answer Mathematica gave me, what is the exact meaning of cubic root of a complex number?

Comment: @DavidLingard  for a  complex number that is not a negative real $r ( \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ with $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \theta < \pi,$ we can take a "principal" cube root $$r^{1/3} \left( \cos \frac{\theta}{3} + i  \sin \frac{\theta}{3}  \right)$$

Comment: Thanks, so that means trigonometric functions are hidden behind that cubic root.